# How to clone/duplicate an entry, using class-based views, with model inheritance?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

So... I try to explain : I have a "generic" model (who should certainly be abstract) **GenericProduct** and his *child* model **Product**. This gives me 2 tables with some entries of course. I want to be able to duplicate an entry, via templates. To do that (Class-based view), I created a class **Duplicate(CreateView, UpdateView)** adn I've overwritten the method **get_object** to set the "pk" to "None". It works, but the pk I get is the pk of the *second* table... So the "duplication" doesn't work...
I can give you some code to test.

But am I doing it the right way ?
In my Generic model I've also created a method

```
def duplicate(self):
    self.save(force_insert=True)
```

How could I use it ?

Thanks

Edit : adding code

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class GenericProduct(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def duplicate(self): # can it help ?
        self.save(force_insert=True)


class Product(GenericProduct):
    pass
```

**form.py**

```
from django.forms.models import ModelForm

class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py** (~CRUD)

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy


class List(ListView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name = "products"
    template_name = "products.html"


class Update(UpdateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductForm
    template_name = "product.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('products')

    def get_object(self):
        reference = self.kwargs['reference']
        p = self.model.objects.get(reference=reference)
        p.pk = None
        return p


class Duplicate(CreateView, UpdateView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "product.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('products')
    form_class = ProductForm

    def get_object(self):
        reference = self.kwargs['reference']
        p = self.model.objects.get(reference=reference)
        p.genericproduct_ptr_id = None
        return p
```

**products.html** (to get the list)

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
    table {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 3px 7px;
    }
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>actions</th>
        <th>reference</th>
        <th>name</th>
    </tr>
{% for product in products %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="{% url 'duplicate' product.reference %}">duplicate</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="{% url 'update' product.reference %}">
                {{ product.reference }}
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
    </tr>
{% empty %}
    <tr>
        <td>no entry</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**product.html** (to edit/duplicate a product)

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="OK" />
    </form>
    <p>
        <a href="{% url 'products' %}">
            back to list of products
        </a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, I think I've found the answer : what do you think about it ?
In **views.py**, I add a CreateView class. And the solution is in the template : the form is correctly filled in thanks to the UpdateView class. The trick is to point the action of the form to the **create** url. So my template became
`[...]
    {% if "duplicate" in request.path|cut:"/" %}{% url "create" as URL %}{% endif %}
    <form action='{{ URL }}' method="post">
[...]`

Answer (score 1):

I make my comment as answer as I am satisfied of it :-) !!

So in **models.py**, no need of `def duplicate(self): self.save(force_insert=True)`
In **views.py**, no need of the `Duplicate` class.
I add too the **urls.py** :

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^products/?$', List.as_view(), name='products'),
    url(r'^create/?$', Create.as_view(), name='create'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<reference>.*)/?$', Update.as_view(), name='update'),
    url(r'^duplicate/(?P<reference>.*)/?$', Update.as_view(), name='duplicate'),
]
```

And where it become possible, in **product.html** :

```
<html>
<body>
    {% if "duplicate" in request.path|cut:"/" %}{% url "create" as URL %}{% endif %}
    <form action='{{ URL }}' method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="OK" />
    </form>
    <p>
        <a href="{% url 'products' %}">
            back to list of products
        </a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The trick is to parse the URL to know if we display the form as a creation or as a duplication. We also could pass an argument in the *url* configuration, but we already have the information in the URL,  so... And then, the form is sent to the ***action*** attribute value : "" (empty) if update, *creation* URL if duplication. That's all.

Regards,